# Utilizar o Enter no F5

Tags: javascript

Boa Tarde!

Tenho um iframe e nele abre um sistema onde precisa utilizar o F5 para dar enter.

Já tentei algumas coisas mas não funcionou... Ele não interage com o que está no iframe.

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <style>
        iframe {
            /* Set the width of the iframe the size you want to transform it FROM */
            width: 640px;
            height: 525px;
            /* apply the transform */
            -webkit-transform:scale(0.25);
            -moz-transform:scale(0.25);
            -o-transform:scale(0.25);
            transform:scale(0.25);
            /* position it, as if it was the original size */
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: -14px;
            zoom:75%;
        }
    </style>

    <head>

        <iframe src ="Meu_Site"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        $('body').keypress(function(e){
        alert(e.which);
        if(e.which == 113)
        {
        e.codepress == 13
        }
        });  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar nesta questão! Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor qual é a necessidade? Como assim usar o F5 pra dar enter? O F5 é um atalho padrão do browser e até mesmo do sistema operacional pra realizar uma atualização de algo.

Comment: No sistema de coletor não vamos utilizar o F5 para atualizar, pois ele fará a função d e <Enter>

Comment: Serão vários "F", F5 = <Enter> F8 = Back Page F2 = Exit

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14707966/3497987

Comment: No `e.codepress == 13` utilize apenas um sinal de igual `= `

Comment: aldux - Não foi... fiz o que vc disse que e não deu certo..

Answer (score 0):

O seu código parece ter alguns erros.
O `<style>` tem de estar dentro de `<head>` e o `<iframe>` tem de estar dentro de `<body>`.

Não sei se você tem o jQuery, mas pelo codigo parece não ter, por isso coloquei o codigo em javascript puro.

O `<script>` precisa estar dentro da pagina do `<iframe>` para funcionar.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style>
        iframe {
            /* Set the width of the iframe the size you want to transform it FROM */
            width: 640px;
            height: 525px;
            /* apply the transform */
            -webkit-transform:scale(0.25);
            -moz-transform:scale(0.25);
            -o-transform:scale(0.25);
            transform:scale(0.25);
            /* position it, as if it was the original size */
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            top: -14px;
            zoom:75%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe src="Meu_Site"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script>
top.document.onkeydown = function(e){
    //definir a tecla clicada
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;

    //verificar se a tecla foi o F5 (116)
    if(key == 116) {
        //não deixar o navegador atualizar
        e.preventDefault();

        //(o seu codigo aqui...)
    }
}
</script>
```